# Date & time text to column

Tags: vba, excel

I have problem with a Text to column macro.

I have an Excel file with different macros and one sheet is a table which a user needs to fill in before running one of the macros. Two of the cells are date and time.

I need to copy a date from one file to another and then split the date from e.g. 19/03/2016 to 3 columns Day, Month and Year i.e. 19, 3 & 2016.  When I record the macro all works fine, but when I run the macro, the date is converted into US format and I get 3, 19 & 2016.  The same applies to time, if I have e.g. 15:30, when recording macro I get 15 and 30 but when I run macro I get 3 & 30.

Below is the code which I use:

```
Sub Reporting_Start_Date()

Application.Workbooks(1).Activate
Sheets("Activity Info").Select
Range("C8").Select
Selection.Copy
Application.Workbooks(2).Activate
Range("O2").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone,
SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Selection.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("O2"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar _
    :="/", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1)), _
    TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
Selection.NumberFormat = "0"

End Sub
```

And recorded macro for time is:

```
Sub Reporting_Start_Time()

Application.Workbooks(1).Activate
Sheets("Activity Info").Select
Range("C9").Select
Selection.Copy
Application.Workbooks(2).Activate
Range("R2").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone,
SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Selection.NumberFormat = "[$-F400]h:mm:ss AM/PM"
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("R2"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar _
    :=":", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 9)), _
    TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
Selection.NumberFormat = "0"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Say we have a cell with a date in *dd/mm/yyyy* format.  Select it and run:

```
Sub DateSplitter()
    Dim ary
    With Selection
        ary = Split(.Text, "/")
        .Offset(0, 1) = ary(o)
        .Offset(0, 2) = ary(1)
        .Offset(0, 3) = ary(2)
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

You can code something similar for time.  The code can easily be modified to handle all the dates or times in a column, etc.

Comment: @ Gary's Student, thank you so much, you are a star. Spent two day trying to write and search for macro which will do exactly what I need it to do.  The time format worked as well, although as I needed everything in columns A-C did few changes to your code but it works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Excellent solution has been provided by member @Gary's Student. Similar to that, the following one allows pasting the entire array containing Day, Month and Year at once to the Range("A1:C1"):

```
Sub TestDateParsing()
    Range("A1:C1") = ParseDateDDMM("16/03/2016")
End Sub

Function ParseDateDDMM(DateDDMM As String) As String()
    ParseDateDDMM = Split(DateDDMM, "/")
End Function
```

This will lead to a slight performance improvement.